# How to simplify nested ajax subscribe call for Angular 6

Tags: angular, dictionary, pipe, subscribe, flatmap

```
getBudgetMap(budgetMonthID){
        this.rows = [];
        this.categoryService.getCategory(budgetMonthID).subscribe(category =>{
            this.categoryList = category;
            this.categoryList.forEach(category => {

                this.transactionService.getTransaction(budgetMonthID, category.id).subscribe(transaction => {
                    this.rows = this.rows.concat(transaction);
                })

            })
        )
    }
```

To make it easy, I have a nested ajax service (http.get) call which the first one `(getCategory)` returning a list of category base on `budgetMonthID`. The number of categories varies. Then each category will make a second call `getTransaction` to retrieve all transactions belong to each category. The code above works fine, but I been reading about `map`, `flapMap`, `pipe` for **Angular**, I just can't figure it out how to change that nasty code. Thanks

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I'm sure you'll get good answers, but I'd argue that this code you have now is far from "nasty" (other than the huge indents :)), and is probably easier to read/maintain than using RxJS operators at all costs. Just my 2 cents tho.

Answer (score 1):

> You can use `rxjs operators` which deals with Asynchronous call. To be preciouse you should use `switchmap` or `flatmap` or `mergemap`. Code can be given to however you will encounter with same problem in future again. So I would encourage you to spare  sometimes to understand how rxjs operator works.

Please walk through this - https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html

Comment: better to learn to use mergeMap as default, instead of switchMap, because the latter can cause ['dataloss'](https://blog.angularindepth.com/switchmap-bugs-b6de69155524) if improperly used

Answer (score 1):

This requires some rxjs knowledge indeed.

```
this.categoryService.getCategory(budgetMonthID).pipe(
  tap((categories) => this.categoryList = categories),
  mergeMap((categories) => zip(
    ...categories.map(
      (category) => this.transactionService.getTransaction(budgetMonthID, category.id)
    )
  )
).subscribe((rows) => {
  this.rows = rows;
});
```

To start we are using [tap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/do.html) to save the categories into the `categoryList`. This is an operator which just executes the function but has no effect on the pipe flow.

After that, we use [mergeMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/mergemap.html) which picks up the categories, and returns another Observable. In this case the [`zip`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/zip.html), which waits for all the parameters to complete before emitting as an array, which will be picked up by the subscribe.

You can also try to have a look at the built-in [`async`](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) pipe from angular. This removes the need of unsubscribing inside your component, and keeps it clean as well. This will change your code to this:

```
this.categoryList$ = this.categoryService.getCategory(budgetMonthID).pipe(
  shareReplay(1)
);

this.rows$ = this.categoryList$.pipe(
  mergeMap((categories) => zip(
    ...categories.map(
      (category) => this.transactionService.getTransaction(budgetMonthID, category.id)
    )
  )
);
```

In your template you can then access this like so:

```
<div *ngFor="let category of categoryList$ | async"></div>
<div *ngFor="let row of rows$ | async"></div>
```

Comment: Should be `this.categoryList = categories`. Also wouldn't `switchMap` be more fitting here? Still not entirely familiar with RxJS but it seems like you no longer need the values from the initial observable after tapping into it.

Comment: @Jeto untested code indeed :) changed the categories thing. And no, you should try to only use switchMap in cases that it makes sense. See my comment on SunilSingh's answer

Comment: Use switchMap, only use mergeMap if you have a good reason for it!

Comment: @Jeto you're welcome. You are right nevertheless though, I can only assume these are ajax requests which complete immediately, which makes concatMap/mergeMap/switchMap all have the same outcome, but personally I even prefer concatMap here, because you really wait for it to complete and describes the code more thoroughly, but opinions differ